# Show Orderby Array value Value in SQL Query When using IN()

Tags: php, sql

Following is my code which retrives cookie value and shows recently viewed products

```
//get cookie vlue
$myCookieArr = array_unique(json_decode($_COOKIE['myshopping']));
//reverce cookie order
$myCookieArry = array_reverse($myCookieArr);
//loop through
foreach ($myCookieArry as $key => $value) {
    $allCProduct .= $value.",";
}
$allCProduct = rtrim($allCProduct,',');

$getRandProduct = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN (".$allCProduct.")" );
```

It Works fine but issue is it is not in order of `array_reverse($myCookieArr)`. so how can i make order by my array value.

So what happen is first viewed product will be last if second one product is viewed by user.let suppose i am getting array as

```
(
 [0] => 35
 [0] => 39
 //This is Two product 
 //i have already seen
)
```

Now if i show third product `40` so order should like

```
(
 [0] => 40
 [1] => 35
 [2] => 39
)
```

NOTE : i don't have issue of security

So how can i achieve that ?

Comment: your code is wide open to **SQL injection**

Comment: show here what you are getting in `$myCookieArr` and `$myCookieArry`....

Comment: `$myCookieArr` Stores All Cookie value and `$myCookieArry` is reverce of cookie array @YashParekh

Comment: what is the value of `myCookieArr`

Comment: why you all are asking completely irrelevant questions?

Comment: `myCookieArr` Strores user product-id

Comment: agree with @YourCommonSense